# Where (and how) can I drop weight safely?

Tags: weight-loss, thigh

I'm a wrestler (I know, you probably think I'm starving myself right now).  Truth be told, I need to lose a couple of pounds (4 or 5) to make the weight class I want.  I'm not sure how feasible this is though.  Contrary to what some wrestlers believe, not eating food to lose weight also reduces your energy - effectively making you a bad wrestler with eating problems.  I'm a pretty light guy.  I'm about 142 pounds.  I'm trying to make it to 138 or less.  As far as my body goes, I'm pretty slim.

**My question:**

How this should my thighs be (sounds random right?-)?  Over all I'm really skinny, I've always thought though, that I have slightly larger thighs.  They aren't overly large though and nobody can really tell.  Is this normal?  How thick should my thighs be assuming I'm a slim guy at 142 pounds.  If they are too big, what exercise can I do to best replace that with muscle and hopefully slim down a bit in that area?

Really, I'm only asking this because I don't know and I feel awkward asking people that I know about thigh size (The internetz, on the other hand, is another story).  I could be normal for all I know.  If I'm normal, I'll accept being 142 and bulk up a bit to compensated for the upper weight class.

If it means anything:

- I'm 5 foot 11 inches
- I weigh 142 pounds
- I'm a male

Comment: Is it just me, or is the title of this question completely unrelated? It says "Where (and how) can I drop weight safely?" for me (which I think is another question somewhere). Bug?

Comment: At your height and weight you might find it easier to go heavier. What is the next class limit?

Comment: How do you know your thighs are larger-than-you-think-they-should be due to "that" (fat?  Is that what you mean?)?  Couldn't it be that your thighs are just large due to their femurs and your leg musculature?  What might give an idea of fattiness is whether you can pinch anything.  Most men do not store fat in their thighs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is **absolutely impossible** to target fat loss to any particular part of your body.

Once again, it is **absolutely impossible** to target where fat will come off.

This is at least one piece of fairly well established science.

{As a footnote, other than, arguably, the notion of your sex hormone balance - which can affect your overall body shape - women and men have different fat patterns - but that is completely irrelevant to something like "fat on my thighs".}

All you can do is smash your intake of carbohydrates, and the FAT on your body will go away, week by week.  But it is absolutely impossible to target WHERE adipose tissue is reduced.

I have no idea if you are (A) starting to put on weight, and that is happening in your thighs or (B) you just happen to have really large manly thighs (like some people are tall, some people have a big nose, etc).

IF the situation is (A), simply smash your carbohydrate intake and exercise more and you will lose the fat from your body, eventually including this fat on the thighs, (To repeat that's only if it IS THE CASE of (A). If it's (B) there is utterly nothing you can do, other than genetic time travel.)

By the way, I also have enormous, rather unsightly, thighs!  Heh!  they look great in a kilt (if you happen to be scottish) but that's about the only advantage.  Or, I could easily play say a speed skater in a movie  :)

Comment: Alright, I'll go ahead take a look at what kind of stuff I eat daily.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: Strike the absoutely impossible. Dr. Tabata showed spot reduction in his initial research in the 90's. It only applies to trained atheletes and not to the level most people hope (a few %), but it is possible.

Comment: @Christopher: big claims require big evidence!  (1) exactly which "spots" of the body did he reduce fat from  (2) exactly how?  It sounds like total nonsense really.  the only way you can grow fat, is with insulin.  There is no other mechanism. insulin == adipose cells intaking triglycerides.  Insulin injections commonly cause fat increase near the site of the injection, over time.  To make one particular part of a human body, empty out it's fat cells, in that particular part of the body, would require (somehow) controlling the hormones in that only area of the body.  Don't you reckon ???

Comment: @Joe I wouldn't call a 15 year old paper a big claim. Tabat's methods have been studied quite a bit since. http://journals.lww.com/acsm-msse/Abstract/1997/03000/Metabolic_profile_of_high_intensity_intermittent.15.aspx

Comment: @Joe Huh? Did you look at the data of measured reduction of leg fat? No, it wasn't the major point, but it was nonetheless observed.

Comment: @Christopher  I don't have access to the whole paper, only the synopsis. (If you have the paper, lemme have it pls!)  They would have had to measure fat in a number of areas of the body. Is that what they did? If so, on which other areas of the body did they measure the fat-reduction?

Comment: Thanks, - however there seems to be some technical problem logging in to chat. It won't let me log in.  I'll try 2morrow..

Comment: Smashing your carb intake doesn't reduce bodyfat. Of course if he doesn't replace those carbs with any other calories, the person will most likely lose fat because they just reduced their overall calorie intake by 40% or more. It's extremely misleading and flawed to say carb intake is the main factor effecting fat loss; It is calorie intake. If low carb automatically meant fatloss, the Inuit would be continuously losing fat and dead.

Comment: Hi @mike, smashing your carb intake does reduce fat. The only action of eating carbohydrates is: to make your pancreas produce insulin.  Insulin's primary overwhelming action: it causes triglycerides to form inside your fat cells. YES, you must also moderate your total calories.  if you eat say 2000 /day, but with 100++g of carbs, you will not lose fat.  If you eat 2000 /day, but with say 40g of that being carbs, fat will just roll off you.  In short, what you say is 100% wrong.  Of course, YOU think that what I say is 100% wrong!!!!  :) it's the great Car Debate. To continue ..

Comment: Mike, I'd guess you think cholesterol is "bad for your heart" and "fat makes you fat".  Both those ideas are totally wrong, though.  (But you would completely disagree with me.)  Again it's the great "Carb Debate", which has two totally opposite sides - and can't be settled in a comment section!  Heh!  BTW the inuit are incredibly healthy.

Comment: For completeness: if you eat 100+ g of carbohydrates per day (not to mention the typical 200, 300, even more...) you will constantly be hungry and would need impossible willpower to eat moderately.  In contrast if you eat the correct amount of carbohydrates for humans (72 grams /day) you are never hungry, and always have energy, and you will only feel the need to eat an appropriate overall # of calories. Dietary CHO == hunger, Dietary Fat = gourmet satisfaction. I just mention this for anyone reading who wants to lose fat!

Comment: "if you eat say 2000 /day, but with 100++g of carbs, you will not lose fat." It's funny, I have worked with dozens of clients who lost plenty of fat eating over 150g of carbs. And no, I don't believe 'fat makes you fat'. Also, it's hilarious you think there is a 'correct' amount of carbohydrates -which somehow is 72 grams per day.

Answer (score 0):

I really advise you to take a look at [Mark Sisson](http://www.marksdailyapple.com/) and [Robb Wolf's](http://robbwolf.com/2011/08/11/big-fat-blog-post-2/) websites. This is a very effective and healthy way to lose weight. Also train muscle groups instead of individual muscles.

Cross Fit is an effective way to do this, but make sure to start at a level that suits you and don't overtrain.

Also take a look at the lowest link that I posted. These are simple workouts that you can do at home that don't take longer than 30 minutes. Also they focus on muscle groups and movement patterns instead of hypertrophy. That way your basal metabolism goes up and you use more energy at rest and during nighttime.

Make sure you stay away from sugar, wheat, vegetable oils, trans fats, and high fructose corn syrup, and you should lose weight like a train!

Comment: Mark Sisson - great tip !!!!!!!!!!!!  the OP should also buy his book "the primal advantage".

Comment: The first sentence in the third paragraph does not really make sense, maybe the link was lost since this was your first answer back then and you were not allowed to post more than two?